# debian jessie apt-get update fails (404)

Tags: linux, debian

I'm a debian novice. I'm just trying to install updates on my vps, and `apt-get update` ends up with 404 errors. I googled for a while and some suggested replacing or regenrating the sources.list file, so I've done that (afaik).

here's my current sources.list:

```
# Debian packages for stable
deb http://mirror.0x.sg/debian/ stable main contrib
# Uncomment the deb-src line if you want 'apt-get source'
# to work with most packages.
# deb-src http://mirror.0x.sg/debian/ stable main contrib

# Security updates for stable
deb http://security.debian.org/ stable/updates main contrib
```

this is my system:

```
root@debbox:/etc/apt# uname -a
Linux debbox 4.8.6-x86_64-linode78 #1 SMP Tue Nov 1 14:51:21 EDT 2016 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I installed and ran netselect-apt to get it to rebuild the sources.list you see above:

```
root@debbox:/etc/apt# apt-get install netselect-apt
... snip ...
Writing sources.list.
Done.
```

but apt-get udpate fails still. not sure what the ftp.utexas stuff comes from.

```
root@debbox:/etc/apt# apt-get update
Ign http://mirror.0x.sg stable InRelease
Get:1 http://mirror.0x.sg stable Release.gpg [2,373 B]                                                       
Get:2 http://mirror.0x.sg stable Release [118 kB]                                                            
Get:3 http://mirror.0x.sg stable/main amd64 Packages [7,095 kB]                                              
Get:4 http://mirror.0x.sg stable/contrib amd64 Packages [50.9 kB]                                            
Ign http://repo.mongodb.org jessie/mongodb-org/3.4 InRelease                                                 
Hit http://repo.mongodb.org jessie/mongodb-org/3.4 Release.gpg                                               
Hit http://repo.mongodb.org jessie/mongodb-org/3.4 Release                                                   
Get:5 http://repo.mongodb.org jessie/mongodb-org/3.4/main amd64 Packages [5,868 B]                           
Get:6 http://mirror.0x.sg stable/contrib Translation-en [45.9 kB]                                            
Get:7 http://mirror.0x.sg stable/main Translation-en [5,393 kB]                                              
Hit http://http.debian.net testing InRelease                                                                 
Ign http://repo.mongodb.org jessie/mongodb-org/3.4/main Translation-en_US                                    
Ign http://repo.mongodb.org jessie/mongodb-org/3.4/main Translation-en                                       
Get:8 http://security.debian.org stable/updates InRelease [62.9 kB]                                          
Get:9 http://http.debian.net testing/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex [27.9 kB]                                 
Get:10 http://security.debian.org stable/updates/main amd64 Packages [128 kB]                                
Ign http://ftp.utexas.edu stable InRelease                                                       
Get:11 http://security.debian.org stable/updates/contrib amd64 Packages [556 B]                  
Get:12 http://security.debian.org stable/updates/contrib Translation-en [256 B]                              
Get:13 http://http.debian.net testing/main Translation-en/DiffIndex [27.9 kB]                                
Get:14 http://security.debian.org stable/updates/main Translation-en [52.7 kB]                               
Ign http://ftp.utexas.edu stable Release.gpg                                                                 
Ign http://ftp.utexas.edu stable Release                                                                     
Ign http://ftp.utexas.edu stable/all Sources/DiffIndex                        
Ign http://ftp.utexas.edu stable/all amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://ftp.utexas.edu stable/all Translation-en_US                                                       
Ign http://ftp.utexas.edu stable/all Translation-en                                                          
Err http://ftp.utexas.edu stable/all Sources                                                                 
  404  Not Found
Err http://ftp.utexas.edu stable/all amd64 Packages                                                          
  404  Not Found
Fetched 13.0 MB in 12s (1,080 kB/s)                                                                          
W: There is no public key available for the following key IDs:
EF0F382A1A7B6500
W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.utexas.edu/dotdeb/dists/stable/all/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.utexas.edu/dotdeb/dists/stable/all/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Any tips appreciated!

Comment: Do you have files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` and their contents?

Comment: ooh i didn't notice that. there's a `dotdeb.list` (which has the ftp.utexas address - `deb http://ftp.utexas.edu/dotdeb/ stable all
deb-src http://ftp.utexas.edu/dotdeb/ stable all`), a `mongodb-org-3.4.list`, and a `testing.list`. how can I tell what they are for? what is dotdeb?

Comment: look what they are hosting in their repositories/what you got installed from those repositories?

Answer (score 0):

APT can also store repository configuration in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`. One of those files likely contains the incorrect line for ftp.utexas.edu; my guess is that instead of `stable/all` it should contain only `stable`.